# Gap between elements is different for some elements

Tags: html, css, ejs

I recently started working on a discord bot dashboard, but there is an issue. When the guilds load, I made servers with no IMG to display as 60x60 gray box with the first letters from every word in the guild name.

If there a guild with an IMG, I resize it to 60x60 pixels. The problem is that if there are two servers without an IMG in a row, the gap is smaller than IMG to IMG/IMG to no IMG.

To store the no IMG guilds I use divs. What is causing this problem? I don't want different gap sizes. How can I achieve this?

```
#guilds div, #guilds img {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

[In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzm0L.png), the first two elements are div, and the others are IMG.

Comment: Can you please share peace of code that you have write ?

Comment: @HirenPatel this is an auto generated code.

`<div class='square' style='<%= font_size %>' data-toggle="tooltip" title="<%= guild.name %>"><%= guild_name %></div>`

`<img src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/<%= guild.id %>/<%= guild.iconHash %>' style='width: 60px; height: 60px; border-radius: 100%;' data-toggle="tooltip" title="<%= guild.name %>">
<br>`

first for the no img, second for the img

Comment: HI , Can you please write demo here : https://codepen.io/

Comment: @HirenPatel i cant because this is discord oauth and this is working with a bot and express. btw i work with ejs, i forgot to add it to the tags

Comment: Just an educated guess: Try to add `display: block;` to your css above.